# Solve $a^3 + (a+1)^3 + ... + (a+6)^3 = b^4 + (b+1)^4$ In integers

Tags: elementary-number-theory

This came in a regional Olympiad. I gave my solution like this:

The LHS is always 0 or 3 modulo 4 while the RHS is always 1 modulo 4. Thus no solutions.

The official solution uses the natural choice of modulo 7 after some algebraic manipulation. Will I get full marks for my approach?

Comment: Yes, your answer is also correct.

Comment: If $a=0$, isn't the left side also 1 modulo 4?

Comment: Seems that generally for $a=4k$ left side is congruent to $1$...

Answer (score 1):

\begin{align*}
LHS &= 7a^3 + 63a^2 + 273a + 441\\
&= 4(a^3 + 15a^2 + 68a + 110) + 2a^2(a+1) + (a^2 + 1)(a + 1)
\end{align*}
Since, $2a^2(a+1)$ is divisible by $4$, therefore,
$$
LHS
\equiv (a^2 + 1)(a + 1) \pmod{4}\\
\equiv
\begin{cases}
0 \pmod{4}, &\text{if $a = 2n +1, n \in \mathbb{Z}$}\\
1 \pmod{4}, &\text{if $a = 4n, n \in \mathbb{Z}$}\\
3 \pmod{4}, &\text{if $a = 4n +2, n \in \mathbb{Z}$}
\end{cases}
$$
Whereas,
\begin{align*}
RHS &= 2b^4 + 4b^3 + 6b^2 + 4b + 1\\
&=2b^2(b^2 + 3) + 4b(b^2 + 1) + 1
\end{align*}
Since, $2b^2(b^2 + 3)$ is divisible by $4$, therefore,
$$
RHS \, \equiv 1 \pmod{4}.
$$
Hence, $LHS = RHS$ might hold when $a = 4n$.

Alternatively,

since $LHS = 7(a^3 + 9a^2 + 39a + 63)$, therefore $LHS \equiv 0 \pmod{7}.$

Now, for $b = 7n + r \quad (n \in \mathbb{Z}, r \in \{0,1,2,3,4,5,6\})$,

$RHS \equiv r^4 + (r + 1)^4 \pmod{7} \neq 0 \quad $(it can be easily verified by putting different values of $r$).

Hence, the given equation has no integral solution.

Answer (score 0):

Working modulo 7 on both sides in a different way
 will solve this problem without expanding $LHS$.

> You can check that for any integer $a$ the set $\{a,a+1,a+2,...,a+6\}$ forms the complete set of residue class modulo $7$.Hence $LHS≡1^3+2^3+3^3+...6^3≡0(mod7)$.
>
> > But you can easily check that $RHS$ is not congruent to $0$ mod $7$ for any integer $b$.Hence there is no such pair of integers $(a,b)$.
> >
> > > $Q.E.D.$

Comment: How does this answer my question?

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: Plz check the ans carefully